# Google Places API grab sublocality_level_1 if exists, else clear a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a text field which allows users to enter their location which returns results (cities) from the Google Places API. Here's the code I'm using to fill in my form fields once a user has selected a location:

```
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  var lat = place.geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6);
  var lng = place.geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6);

  var components = place.address_components;
  for (var i = 0, component; component = components[i]; i++) {
        if (component.types[0] == 'locality') {
            $('#id_city').val(component['long_name'])
        }
        if (component.types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
            $('#id_state').val(component['short_name'])
        }
        if (component.types[0] == 'country') {
            $('#id_country_short').val(component['short_name'])
        }
        if (component.types[0] == 'country') {
            $('#id_country_long').val(component['long_name'])
        }
        if (component.types[0] == 'sublocality_level_1') {
            $('#id_region').val(component['long_name'])
        }else{
            $('#id_region').val('')
        }
    }
  $('#lat').val(lat)
  $('#lng').val(lng)
}
```

Pretty straight forward, but there's not always a "region" (or sublocality_level_1) selected with their location. What I'm attempting to do is clear the #id_region field of any old regions if the new location they've selected does not have a region/sublocality_level_1. The problem is that even if a sublocality_level_1 is present, the code still seems to hit the "else" statement which clears the #id_region text field.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You are only looking at the first member of the types array, there are usually more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem exists because of the structure of your `if...else` for a `region`. Because you are in a loop if there is any `component` in the `components` array after the one that is a `region` it will ... clear the region.

Remove the `else` from the loop. Clear the `region` before you start looping. That way if there is a `region` in the set, you'll fill it in and if there isn't it will stay empty.

```
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  var lat = place.geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6);
  var lng = place.geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6);

  var components = place.address_components;

  $('#id_region').val('');

  for (var i = 0, component; component = components[i]; i++) {
        if (component.types[0] == 'locality') {
            $('#id_city').val(component['long_name'])
        }
        if (component.types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
            $('#id_state').val(component['short_name'])
        }
        if (component.types[0] == 'country') {
            $('#id_country_short').val(component['short_name'])
        }
        if (component.types[0] == 'country') {
            $('#id_country_long').val(component['long_name'])
        }
        if (component.types[0] == 'sublocality_level_1') {
            $('#id_region').val(component['long_name'])
        }
    }
  $('#lat').val(lat)
  $('#lng').val(lng)
}
```

Comment: Well... now I feel like an idiot. I can't believe it was that simple after I've spent so much time trying to get this if/else to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @gforce301 said, you also need to process through all the types in the component:

```
  var components = place.address_components;
  $('#id_region').val('')
  for (var i = 0, component; component = components[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < component.types.length; j++) {
      if (component.types[j] == 'locality') {
        $('#id_city').val(component['long_name'])
      }
      if (component.types[j] == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
        $('#id_state').val(component['short_name'])
      }
      if (component.types[j] == 'country') {
        $('#id_country_short').val(component['short_name'])
      }
      if (component.types[j] == 'country') {
        $('#id_country_long').val(component['long_name'])
      }
      if (component.types[j] == 'sublocality_level_1') {
        $('#id_region').val(component['long_name'])
      }
    }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vg5sr9gn/2/)
(places with sublocality_level_1: Brooklyn, NY; Śródmieście, Warsaw, Poland)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  var lat = place.geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6);
  var lng = place.geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6);

  var components = place.address_components;
  $('#id_region').val('')
  for (var i = 0, component; component = components[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < component.types.length; j++) {
      if (component.types[j] == 'locality') {
        $('#id_city').val(component['long_name'])
      }
      if (component.types[j] == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
        $('#id_state').val(component['short_name'])
      }
      if (component.types[j] == 'country') {
        $('#id_country_short').val(component['short_name'])
      }
      if (component.types[j] == 'country') {
        $('#id_country_long').val(component['long_name'])
      }
      if (component.types[j] == 'sublocality_level_1') {
        $('#id_region').val(component['long_name'])
      } else {
        // $('#id_region').val('')
      }
    }
  }
  $('#lat').val(lat)
  $('#lng').val(lng)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" />
</div>

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
      <input class="field" id="route" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
             You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
             https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
        -->
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="id_city" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="id_state" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td class="label">Region</td>
    <td class="wideField">
      <input class="field" id="id_region" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="id_country_long" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="id_country_short" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="lat" />
<input id="lng" />
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work great. I'm a little confused though on the for `(var j = 0; j < component.types.length; j++)` line that you added. Sorry, I've been fumbling my way through this looking at Stack Overflow posts and a lot of it is a bit confusing for me. What does that line do?

Comment: To add, it appears to give me the same results without or without your added code. So I'm not sure what it's actually doing. Thanks